# Linear algebraic method for identifying functions from vectors of coefficients from truncated power series?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

Assume we have a truncated power series solution to some equation represented as a vector of coefficients to that power series. Then how can we use linear algebra to calculate the analytic expression?

For example we can express the differential equation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478718/solve-fracdydx-frac2yx1-x-using-integrating-factor-method?noredirect=1#comment5121290_2478718) like this:

$${\bf ((X+I)D-2I)v = (X+I)}[0,1,0,\cdots]^T$$
Where we are to solve for $\bf v$, and $\bf I$ represents multiplication by the function $1$, $\bf X$ represents multiplication by $x$ and $\bf D$ represents differentiation.

Now, how to find the expression of the function from that vector $\bf v$ with help of linear algebra?

Comment: In general you will get countably many linear equations of the coordinates $v_1,\ldots, v_n,\ldots$ of $\mathbf{v}$. Then you get a recursive formula. And if you are lucky then you will be able to get an explicit formula for $v_n$. That's how you can solve an ODE by power series.

Comment: ***Astonishing***!